# RealmSwiftで'Invalid predicate expressions'という例外について

Tags: swift, ios, realm

以下のようなコードを実行すると

```
'Invalid predicate expressions', reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'
```

というエラーが発生します(シミュレータで確認しています)。
`no`プロパティは`Log`エンティティの`Int`型プロパティです。

Realmのバージョンは

- Realm (2.4.3):

  - Realm/Headers (= 2.4.3)
- Realm/Headers (2.4.3)
- RealmSwift (2.4.3):

  - Realm (= 2.4.3)

です。

```
func search() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        var results = realm.objects(Log.self).filter("no == %d", 5)
        for l in results {
            print("search result is \(l.no):\(l.message)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("error occured")
    }
}
```

`Log`エンティティの`no`プロパティの名前を`logNo`に変えるとエラーは起きません(`nn`とか２文字にもしてみましがエラーは起きませんでした)。
これはRealmの仕様でしょうか。それともバグでしょうか。
ドキュメントにはそれらしい記述は見当たりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それはRealmが利用しているiOSのクエリAPI（NSPredicate）の仕様です。

`no`（あるいは`NO`）はObjective-Cの真偽値リテラルに使用される予約語ですので、クエリ文中で使用すると、真偽値と解釈されるので構文エラーとなってしまいます。

これを避けるにはキー値を置換するための`%K`という書き方をします。

```
var results = realm.objects(Log.self).filter("%K == %d", "no", 5)
```

上記のように`%K`を`no`で置き換える、と書くと大丈夫です。